# polyglossia \textenglish{} produces extra spaces, while \textspanish{} works properly

Tags: polyglossia

I'm working on multilingual documents and noticed that the command `\textenglish` gets extra spaces in output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{french}
  \setotherlanguages{english,spanish}
\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Résumé:} Et voilà!

\noindent \textenglish{\textbf{Summary:}} Here it is.

\noindent \textspanish{\textbf{Resumen:}} Esto está bien.    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of MWE with English text surrounded with extra spaces]

The French and Spanish lines are correct, the English one is not. I'm getting too much space before *Summary* and before *Here*, that is, around `\textenglish{}`. (Of course, *Here it is* would be marked as English as well, but that's another matter. :-)

I usually work with the `memoir` class and `xelatex.`

I tried placing some `\ignorespaces,` inside or around the `\textenglish,` but to no avail.

Can anyone help correcting this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

missing `%` in `gloss-english` but you can correct it in document:

**Note** This is already fixed in the sources for the next release.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

  \setdefaultlanguage{french}
  \setotherlanguages{english,spanish}

\makeatletter
\def\english@language{%
   \polyglossia@setup@language@patterns{\english@variant}%egreg's favourite
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Résumé:} Et voilà!

\noindent \textenglish{\textbf{Summary:}} Here it is.

\noindent \textspanish{\textbf{Resumen:}} Esto está bien.    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same is also happening with french, greek and portuges. The same hack fixes french and greek as well, thanks again. But `portuges` remains broken. Catalan, ngerman and italian all work fine in this respect.